# Watch OS - is it possible to gather data from all the sensors?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I need to build a Watch OS application that gathers and sends the data collected from all the sensors of a series 2 watch:

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- GPS / GLONASS
- Light sensor
- Heart rate

Is it possible to collect this data programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single framework to do this, but you can access each sensor using the following framework:

- Accelerometer and Gyroscope - [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager), available watchOS2+
- GPS - [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation), available watchOS2+
- Heart Rate - [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit), available watchOS2+, for accessing continuous measurements, use [HKWorkout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout)
- Light Sensor - this is the only one that is not available even in `watchOS3`